Asymptotic upper bound on nullity of biadjacency matrix of connected bipartite graph of bounded-degree
Let $G$ be a bipartite graph with parts $V$ and $W$ of sizes $m$ and $n$, respectively. The edge-set is $E \subseteq V \times W$. The adjacency matrix of $G$ takes the form
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & H \\
H^T & 0
\end{pmatrix}~,
$$
where $H$ is an $m \times n$ matrix known as the biadjacency matrix. Assume that $G$ is connected and has maximum degree $\Delta \ge 1$, so the number of $1$'s in each row and each column of $H$ is at most $\Delta$. These assumptions together also imply that $m$ has to grow linearly in $n$.
I am interested in the asymptotic behaviour of $k = \dim \ker H$ as $n$ is increased with fixed $\Delta$. Obviously, $0\le k\le n$.
Question: Is there some $\epsilon >0$ such that $k/n \le 1-\epsilon$ for sufficiently large $n$? Or is there at least a weaker bound like $1-k/n$ is larger than $c/n$ for any constant $c>0$ and for all sufficiently large $n$?

Motivation: In error-correcting code community, $G$ is known as the Tanner graph and $H$ is known as the parity-check matrix. Since $G$ has a fixed maximum degree, the matrix $H$ is sparse, so one can associate a low-density parity check code to this graph. In this setting, the quantity $k/n$ is known as the rate. So my question is asking if the rate is always bounded away from $1$.

Attempt: There is some literature in graph theory on upper bounds on the nullity $\eta(G) = \dim \ker A$ of a graph $G$. See Survey on Nullity of Graphs for example. In particular, for a connected graph $G$ on $N$ vertices, with maximum degree $\Delta \ge 1$, $\eta(G) \le \left(\frac{\Delta-1}{\Delta}\right) N$. However, in my case $N=n+m$ and $\eta(G) = k + k'$, where $k'= \dim \ker H^T$. I don't see an obvious way to use this bound to answer the above question. There are also other bounds on the nullity of bipartite graph but they also involve the total number of vertices $N$, rather than $n$.

The graph-theory bounds I mentioned in the question are actually enough to answer to my question in the positive.
Let $r$ be the rank of the matrix $H$. It is also the rank of its transpose $H^T$, and so the rank of $A$ is $2r$. By the rank-nullity theorem, we have $k+r = n$, $k'+r=m$, and $\eta(G) + 2r = N = n+m$. Using the upper bound $\eta(G) \le \left( \frac{\Delta-1}{\Delta}\right) N$, we get the lower bound $r \ge N/2\Delta$. Therefore,
$$
k \le n - N/2\Delta \le \left( 1-\frac{1}{2\Delta}\right)n~.
$$
where I used $N \ge n$. In fact, using the inequality $n/\Delta \le m$ (because $G$ is connected and has maximum degree $\Delta$), one can improve this bound to
$$
k \le \left( 1- \frac1{2\Delta} - \frac1{2\Delta^2} \right)n = \left(1+\frac1{2\Delta}\right)\left(\frac{\Delta-1}{\Delta}\right)n ~.
$$
